# Understanding Single Sign On relating to OpenID

Tags: openid, single-sign-on

I am not sure whether I understand SSO correctly. I think the main idea is to have only one username/password for many sites. And another idea of SSO is to log in only once so that you can use every other site with the same SSO mechanism without logging in again.
The first goal is definitely implemented by OpenID. But what about the second one? If I log in to stackoverflow with facebook, I won't be logged in automatically to other sites which also uses the facebook login, will I? So If you have an OpenID, do you always have to enter your username and password for each site?

Comment: Umm...I just noticed that you cannot make a cookie cross domain compatible. For this reason alone I think it isn't possible to implement SSO with OpenID unless the sites are in some bond of trust.

Comment: NO, it is possible to implement SSO with OpenID, look at my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have understood about SSO is correct. And Yes you can implement SSO with OpenID and in case of Facebook, you are not using OpenID to login to StackOverflow, its OAuth.

The way to implement SSO with OpenID is not using a cross domain cookie, but with a cookie set at the OpenID Provider domain. So every the user is being redirected to the OP by a SP, the OP see this cookie and identifies that this user is already logged in and has a valid session, so the user will be immediately redirected back to the RP without any authentication challenge.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product. I have removed the link from this answer, since the answer seems to stand on its own otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct about the main idea. The advantage of openID is precisely that - to be able to re-use credentials.

The basic process is simple (using your example of logging into StackOverflow with Facebook).

1. You visit stackoverflow.
2. You say "I am CommanderData on facebook".
3. Stackoverflow says "Really? Prove it!" - and then it goes to facebook and asks "Is this guy really CommanderData on facebook?"
4. If you are logged in on facebook already, facebook replies "Yes, he is in fact CommanderData on facebook", and now StackOverflow can log you in, knowing that you are who you say you are on facebook. If you are not logged in on facebook, facebook should give you the chance to prove that you are CommanderData by logging into facebook, and then it will reply to StackOverflow.

So to answer your question: If you log into SO with facebook, you will not automatically be logged into any other sites using Facebook OpenId. However, if you are logged into facebook, you should not have to log into facebook every single time because facebook already knows who you are, and can tell the RP (relying party, StackOverflow in your example) who you are.

As for your comment: I don't believe OpenId uses Cross domain cookies. It makes individual web requests that are validated on both sides (EP and RP) and then there is no more communication between the two. StackOverflow is not actually reading your facebook authorization cookie.

You may find [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/daveman692/openid-bootcamp-tutorial) informative.